# Keep getting None value after calling string from list chosen by using random

Tags: python, string, list, function, random

So Im making game Rock,paper,Scissors and my problem is I keep getting **None** value after calling variable that contains randomly chosen string from list ''tools''.

```
import random

tools =["Rock","Scissors","Paper"]
def computer_predicion():
    computer_pred = random.choice(tools)
print(computer_predicion())
```

Comment: there is no return statement in the function

Comment: ```return computer_pred``` is what you're looking for

Comment: Next error return outside function

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your return statement in the function. When there is no return value specified, it will return `None` which is what you're seeing on your console when you print it to console. The return statement has to be inside the function.

```
import random

tools =["Rock","Scissors","Paper"]
def computer_predicion():
    computer_pred = random.choice(tools)
    return computer_pred
print(computer_predicion())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understood mistake I made.